# how can i create object without using new keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

**logger.js**

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');

class Logger {
  constructor() {
    this.logger = createLogger({
      transports: new transports.File({
        level: 'error',
        filename: 'error.log',
        format: format.json(),
        ``
      }),
    });
  }

  logError(err) {
    this.logger.error(err);
  }
}

module.exports = Logger;
```

As you can see I am using prototype method.So that I don't have to use new method to create object. I have attached all the 3 files. Just want to know how can I use logger in user.js file without using new keyword in logger.js file.

**user.js**

```
exports.postUser = async (req, res, next) => {

      try {

        console.log(`name:${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`)

        throw new Error('this is an error on the post');

        let user = new User({
          name: req.body.name,
          age: parseInt(req.body.age),
          city: req.body.city,
          status: 'ACTIVE'
        })

        let savedPost = await user.save();
        console.log(`savedPost':${JSON.stringify(savedPost)}`);
        res.json(savedPost);
      } catch (err) {

        console.log(`err:${err.toString()}`)
        res.status(500).json({ message: err })
```

here I want to call the logger .So that it can return method, err, date.

```
logger.prototype.logError = function() {
  return (`function:controller.postUser, error:${err.toString()} -method: ${req.method}- body:${JSON.stringify(req.body)}  date:${new Date(Date.now()).toUTCString()}`)
}
};
```

**routes.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const { json } = require('body-parser');
const User = require('../models/user');
const controller = require('../controllers/user');
const middle = require('../middleware/middleware')

/*routes*/
router.get('/', controller.getUser);

router.post('/', middle.verify, controller.postUser);

router.put('/:userId', controller.updateUser)

router.delete('/:userId', controller.deleteUser);

module.exports = router
```

Comment: If using "classes" or constructor functions, you can't.

Comment: So I will have to use new for sure, to call logger. Is not there any other way?

Comment: If logger is a constructor function or a class, they will rely on `this`. If you use them without new you get `TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with 'new'` or you may find the logger doesn't work properly.

Comment: That's why prototype property is not working here. Thank you

Comment: That may not be the exact reason the prototype property you're adding is not working.

Comment: I used new keyword and it worked. In user.js file I called logger.logError(`....`) and It worked.

Comment: I'm glad it is working

Comment: If you can do it in other way. Please help with that.

Comment: Why do you want another way?

Comment: My senior has asked me to use logger without using new keyword, I am confused how to execute that.

Comment: Then don't use a class in logger.js, use a function. Don't use `this` and then don't use `new`

Comment: Can you help it by providing the desired code without using class. If you can,Help me with that. I have used logger only by using classes. Provide me the desired code, If you can.

Comment: Why not just export the logger directly? `module.exports = createLogger({ ...`?

Comment: After using function,its still causing the same error.

Comment: What error do you mean? Are you still using `prototype`?

Comment: function Logger(){
        let logger=createLogger({
            transports:
                new transports.File({
                level:'error',
                filename:'error.log',
                format:format.json(),
            }),

     logError(err){
    logger.error(err);    
    }
})
    }

Comment: logger.prototype.logError=function(){
            return(`function:controller.postUser, error:${err.toString()} -method: ${req.method}- body:${JSON.stringify(req.body)}  date:${new Date(Date.now()).toUTCString()}`)
    }

Comment: yes i am using prototype

Comment: I would recommend creating a new question a only containing the logger code (as well as a short explanation). As that's where the issue lies. This question has changed from it's original intent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228479/discussion-between-raj-rupam-and-evolutionxbox).

Comment: Its not working, Still getting errors.